# How to integrate xUnit.net with CruiseControl.net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, xunit.net, ccnet-config

I have a continuous integration server that discovers and runs assemblies with NUnit tests.  I would like to add some assemblies with xUnit.net tests to the mix.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download xunit-build-xyzw.zip from [xUnit.net on CodePlex](http://xunit.codeplex.com/releases) and extract it to, for example, `C:\Program Files\xUnit.net`.  Add this location to `PATH` environment variable

   - be sure to have no trailing semicolon
2. Modify your CC.NET `*.build` script to discover assemblies by convention, as outlined below

   - note that command line argument syntax no longer has equals sign
3. In `C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ccnet.config`, Merge XML files produced by NUnit runner and by xUnit.net runner, as outlined below

   - merging happens after build, irrespective of build status
   - be sure results of test run get deleted in the beginning of build script
4. Restart CC.NET
5. Download `xUnitSummary.xsl` from [xUnit.net on GitHub](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/master/tools) and place it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\WebDashboard\xsl`
6. In `C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\WebDashboard\dashboard.config`, modify buildPlugins element as outlined below
7. Restart IIS

Additional info:
[CruiseControl.Net – Server Installation at Neal's Blog](http://bladeoz.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/cruisecontrol-net-server-installation/)

---

Step 2:

```
<project default="RunTests_xUnit">
   <target name="RunTests_xUnit" description="Runs the discovered xUnit.net unit tests" depends="someCompileStep">

      <!-- Outer loop to search through a list of different locations -->
      <!-- Folders to be searched should listed as a semicolon deliminated list in the 'in' attribute -->
      <foreach item="String" in="${TestAssemblyOutputPath}" delim=" ;" property="testsPath">
         <echo message="Searching for xUnit.net test suites in ${testsPath}" />

        <!-- Inner loop to search for dlls containing unit tests -->
        <foreach item="File" property="filename">
          <in>
            <items basedir="${testsPath}">
                  <!-- see http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/types/fileset.html for how to include or exclude specific files or file patterns -->

                  <!-- attempt to run tests in any dlls whose name ends with UnitTestSuite.dll' -->
                  <include name="**UnitTestSuite.dll" />
            </items>
          </in>
          <do>
            <property name="testDLLName" value="${path::get-file-name-without-extension(filename)}" />
            <echo message="Testing ${testDLLName} with xUnit.net" />

               <exec program="${xunit-console.exe}" failonerror="true" resultproperty="resultVal">
                  <arg line="${testsPath}\${testDLLName}.dll /xml ${xUnitTestLogsFolder}${testDLLName}-xUnitResults.xml" />
               </exec>
               <fail message="Failures reported in ${testDLLName}." failonerror="true" unless="${int::parse(resultVal)==0}" />
          </do>
        </foreach>
      </foreach>
   </target>
</project>
```

Step 3:

```
<publishers>
   <merge>
      <files>
         <file>C:\logs-location\xUnitTestLogs\*UnitTestSuite-xUnitResults.xml</file>
         <file>C:\logs-location\TestLogs\*Tests-Results.xml</file>
      </files>
   </merge>
   <xmllogger />
   <statistics />
</publishers>
```

Step 5:

```
<buildPlugins>
    <buildReportBuildPlugin>
        <xslFileNames>
         ...
            <xslFile>xsl\xUnitSummary.xsl</xslFile>
        </xslFileNames>
    </buildReportBuildPlugin>
    ...
   <xslReportBuildPlugin description="xUnit.net Report" actionName="xUnitReport" xslFileName="xsl\xUnitSummary.xsl" />
   ...
</buildPlugins>
```